# How this indefinite integral can be performed?

Tags: calculus

$$
\int\frac{A\sin(x) - \cos(x)}{\sin(x) - A \cos(x)}\,dx
$$

How can we check the existence of this integral?

Can this function be integrated using substitution? If yes, then what substitution should be made?

Answer (score 3):

Or, if for some constant $a,b$, we can express

$\cfrac {A \sin(x) - \cos(x)}  {\sin(x) - A \cos(x)}$

as

$\cfrac {a( \sin(x) - A \cos(x))-b(\cos(x)+A\sin(x))}  {\sin(x) - A \cos(x)}$

$=a-b \cfrac {\mathrm{d}(\sin(x)-A\cos(x))/\mathrm{d}x}  {\sin(x) - A \cos(x)}$

Then, it can be easily separated and integrated.

we have

$a-bA=A$

$aA+b=1$

$\implies a=\cfrac {2A}{1+A^2}, b=\cfrac {1-A^2}{1+A^2}$

hence $\displaystyle \int \cfrac {A \sin(x) - \cos(x)}  {\sin(x) - A \cos(x)} \mathrm{d} x=\cfrac {2A}{1+A^2} x-\cfrac {1-A^2}{1+A^2}\ln \left|\sin x-A\cos x\right|+C$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $$\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$
$$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$
$$dx=\frac{2dt}{1+t^2}$$
the so-called Weierstrass substitution.